# Unable to run background thread and loading wx GUI at the same time

Tags: python, wxpython, python-multithreading

to summarize my problem, I want to load my programs main layout but at the same time run a background daemon to check for tasks in the database and notify the user. I am executing the daemon in a thread with wx.CallAfter but when loading the program the GUI freezes until the thread processes all of the notifications then loads == it doesn't run in the background.

Basically what I tried is: 
- run the script in a thread 
- run the thread with a CallAfter method

Here is an extract of my mainframe (only part of it as its too big):

```
[code]
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "ICSOFT", size = (1400,700))

[...]
    wx.CallAfter(notdaemon)

[...]
def notdaemon():
    import notdaemon
    thread = threading.Thread(target=notdaemon.rundaemon(None), args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

here is an extract of notdaemon:

```
def rundaemon(self):
    for i, a in reminders.items():
        [...]
        notwin = wx.adv.NotificationMessage(u'test', message=msg, parent=None, flags=wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        notwin.Show()
        time.sleep(5.5)
```

So the GUI just freezes until rundaemon displays all notifications..

Any ideas or help is very much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hanging because you're actually *starting* the `rundaemon` function when you're passing it to the Thread. What you're actually passing is the return value, when you really intend to pass the function itself.

Instead of this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=notdaemon.rundaemon(None), args=())
```

Try this:

```
# notice the `rundaemon` function hasn't been called yet (parentheses have been removed)
thread = threading.Thread(target=notdaemon.rundaemon, args=())
```

The `Thread` module will call your function for you, so be careful not call it yourself. If you need to call it with arguments, specify those arguments in the `args` tuple of the `Thread` class initializer.

Comment: amazing catch ! thanks a lot, in addition i just remove the 'self' argument from the function and it worked as you suggested.. :) one problem though, how do i kill the thread on app exit ? when closed the thread is still running in the background

Comment: Glad to help. If you found my answer useful, please upvote it and be sure to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: The `self` argument is only used for class methods. So, since your function is not within a class, you don't need or want it. As for killing the thread when the thread exits, setting `daemon = true` as you already did should have taken care of it... Maybe the main portion of your code isn't exiting as expected. You can try using `import sys` and running `sys.exit(0)`.

Comment: the sys .exit did the trick :) again many many thanks for the help !